# After upgrade to flutter 3.19 . key pad not opening on android 12 mobile phones

Tags: android, flutter, android-12, android-keypad, flutter-textformfield

I am implementing application in flutter. Recently, i upgraded my flutter to 3.19.4 and i am facing lots of bug. like i am unable to open the keypad in my app. On other Android versions, it was working fine, but on Android 12, its not working.

It is working only when I select the keypad icon on the bottom and change it to Google Voice Typing from Gboard.

I tried to add hardwareaccelerated=true in my manifest, but still its not working.

here is [image]

what can i do please any one know about anything please help me.